# Array in NgClass with method call and variable

Tags: angular, ng-class

I want to use `[ngClass]` with a method call that returns an object like `{currentWeek: true}` and I want to add the var `week.state` that can have the value `rejected`.

I want that the HTML looks like this: `<div class="currentWeek rejected"></div>` but when I use it I get this error:

`Error in ./FlexCalendar class FlexCalendar - inline template:29:13 caused by: NgClass can only toggle CSS classes expressed as strings, got [object Object]`

How can I combine a method call and a variable into the ngClass? Something like `[ngClass]=[setWeekClasses(week), week.state]`

```
setWeekClasses(week: Week): Object {
    let state: string = this.state(week.state);
    return {
        'currentWeek': week.weekNumber === this.selectedDate.getWeekNumber(),
        [week.state]: true,
    };
}
```

Comment: Can you add your method where you return the object?

Comment: @echonax Added ;)

Comment: Just correct it to `[ngClass]=setWeekClasses(week)` that's it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a method and a variable to construct the classes-string for the ngClass.

For example see here a class providing a method and a object variable providing class information:

```
class { 

   getCSSClass() {
     return  { state: "rejected" }
   }

 week:object = {
    state: 'rejected'
  }
}
```

In Template then you can use a method and a variable to construct the classes-string for the ngClass.

```
   <div [ngClass]="getCSSClass().state + ' currentWeek'">">
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
   </div>
```

or you can write:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div [ngClass]="week.state + ' ' + getCSSClass().state">
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
    </div>
  `,
})
```

Check here in plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/JfN5cjbCjNAUs8qx9oh1

Comment: Why can i not write something like `[ngClass]=[week.state, getWeekState(week)]`

Comment: I updated answer and plunker; I guess what you want to write is not supported by ngClass grammar. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgClass-directive.html

Comment: I added new code explaining to my question. But I think it is not possible with ngClass to combine a method call and a variable

Comment: I did in plunker. Check it there

Comment: If you do some tracing, you'll find that this pattern causes repeated / infinite digest loops, as Angular appears to be unsure that the returned value of the function...

Answer (score 7):

Binding to a method or function is discouraged and returning a new object instance is especially bad.

You should at least cache the result

```
oldWeek;
oldStyles;
setWeekClasses(week: Week): Object {
    if(this.oldWeek != week) {
      let state: string = this.state(week.state);
      this.oldStyles = {
        'currentWeek': week.weekNumber === this.selectedDate.getWeekNumber(),
        [week.state]: true,
      };
      this.oldWeek = week;
    }

    return this.oldStyles;
}
```

then you can use it like

```
[ngClass]="setWeekClasses(week)"
```

This binding

```
[ngClass]=[week.state, getWeekState(week)]
```

is invalid because `ngClass` supports a string, a list of strings and an object with string values while `[week.state, getWeekState(week)]` results in a list that contains a string and an object, which is not supported.

Comment: Great explanation. Thanks. Even having an `undefined` in the array will result in error rendering.